# Пауза в C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Подскажите, как можно сделать паузу в программе на некоторое время?

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```

вешает полностью программу.

Comment: Либо дайте полный код, либо ищите ошибку в другом месте, поскольку `Sleep(500)` должен приостановить выполнение текущего потока на `500ms` и ничего более.

Comment: полный код слишком большой :)

Comment: private void pr()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
Thread my = new Thread(pr);
            my.Start();
тоже не помогает

Comment: Уточните задачу, ибо приведенный вами код делает именно то, что вы просите.

Comment: задача такая, что у меня некоторые действия должны выполняться через определенный промежуток времени

Comment: А таймер для чего?

Comment: да вот не получается что-то с таймером, хоть и пытался

Comment: а как таймер делал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Образец подхода:

1. запустить новый поток,
2. в потоке зайти цикл,
3. в цикле выполнить работу и заснуть на время.

Пример кода:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class ThreadExample {
    public static void ThreadProc() {
        while (true) {
            // TODO: Здесь выполняется то, что нужно
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public static void Main() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));

        t.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        t.Join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если время совершения операций существенно, то этот вариант не подойдет автору, поскольку будет выполняться через *недетерминированные* промежутки времени.

Comment: в таком случае логичнее использовать [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)

    private static AutoResetEvent event = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public static void ThreadProc() {
        while (true) {
            // TODO: Здесь выполняется то, что нужно
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            event.Set(); // освобождаем заблокированный поток
        }
    }

    t.Start();

    event.WaitOne(); // блокируем текущий поток

    t.Join();

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer // для WPF интерфейса
System.Timers.Timer
System.Web.UI.Timer
System.Threading.Timer
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.CreateTimer(int) + (Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.TimerElapsed)
```

1. создать таймер
2. Задать интервал
3. Подписаться на событие `Tick , Elapsed , etc`
4. `Start()`

Есть еще интересный класс. Называется `Stopwatch`. Это секундомер по-русски. Точность зависит от тактовой частоты процессора

Если нужно выполнять задание в отдельном потоке рекомендуется использовать `BackgroundWorker`. Находится в `System.Windows.Forms`